# Beginners help C# showing a filepath in text box

Tags: c#, textbox, filepath, openfiledialog

I'm new to programming and am using C# and Visual Studio Express 2012.  I am creating a windows form and have inserted a button which runs open file dialog when clicked.  I have a text box on the form that I'd like to have show the file path of the file that the user selected.  I have found some code examples on this site but struggle to understand where they should be placed in the code structure as the examples are often standalone snippets.  I hope its not too dumb a question!

Thanks in advance

Lee

The answer in case it's of use to anyone was.......

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (FileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (DialogResult.OK == fileDialog.ShowDialog())
            {
                string filename = fileDialog.FileName;

                textBox1.Text = fileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have found the code samples, show us them here please.

Comment: Spoon feeding tutorial is [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog)

Comment: Hi, by complete fluke i've just worked out how to do it.  I've copied the code below.  I just added textbox1.text = filedialog.filename in the middle of the code.

Comment: Thanks Sriram, I did see that article but I didn't understand it and how it could help.  No worries anyway and thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `OpenFileDialog` has property `FileName` that contains the path of the selected file, assign that to your `TextBox.Text`

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    yourTextBox.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    textbox.text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```